# Twilio Calling from Browser - AngularJs front end and Java backend

Tags: twilio

Can someone give an example of code for calling phone and receiving phone from browser through Twilio. I am using Java backend and AngularJs at front end.

I went through lots of blogs and twilio tutorials but not successful

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working? Are there errors? Can you share some code you've written?

Comment: Philnash, I tried exactly this one: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/client/browser-to-browser-calls  Here no error nor it is not getting executed. I have doubt that Twilio.Device.connect(params); is not getting connected and when Java Call method will be called.

Comment: Have you tried checking the browser console log? That normally gives some information since the quickstart turns debugging on.

Comment: Yes Phinash, in that I only see error of some twilo.js few are not recognised etc.

Comment: In order for me to help, I need to know what those errors are. Can you edit your question and add the errors that you are seeing please?

Comment: Philnash, I am getting error as Connection Declined, this coming after I done ngrok, not sure is this affected.

Comment: Here is the exact error:
{code: 31002, message: "Connection Declined", connection: a}
twilio.min.js:57 [Connection] Disconnecting...
twilio.min.js:57 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
twilio.min.js:57 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"

Comment: Could you go through the entire process of setting up a call and paste the whole log from the browser console into your question, please?